# Load external page on to Cordova/Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cordova

I have a Cordova/Phonegap application. that on start checks the internet connection.
Actually the app executes local files, but I would, that when there is internet connection, my app loads an external webpage (which is the online version of my app).

How can I achieve this? I have already the script for check internet connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can Load an external page to the app using Jquery load() or by Ajax or by InApp browser.

If you want to show the external page to a div, you can do it by load() or by ajax call

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Load"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="ajax"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
/*Using Jquery Load()*/
$('#Load').load('http://www.google.co.in');

/*Using ajax*/
$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:'http://www.google.co.in',
  success:function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html($(data).children());   
  }
});
```

OR by **[Inapp browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)**

```
 window.open('http://www.google.co.in','_self');
```

go through the **[documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)**

Before using inappbrowser you must install the plugin to your project
To add inappbrowser to project by commanline

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: `.load` seems to be broken (not sure intentionally) in Cordova 6 on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm crazy, can't you just XHR the page and add it to the DOM? If using jQuery, just do it with `$.get` method.

syntax -

```
$.get(url, [data], [callback], [type])
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Camden! But, can you show me an example of this, please?