# Cordova Windows 10 "content src=<external-address>" not working

Tags: windows, cordova, mobile, windows-10-universal

Visual Studio 2015
Tool for Apache Cordova Project.  Created using:-

```
cordova create hello com.somedomain.blah HelloWorld
cordova platform add windows
```

**config.xml**

```
Common: Start Page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/
Common: Domain Access: *
```

When run, either on a device (Windows 10 Mobile) or emulator, the project does not load the start page.  No error output is given, it just doesn't do anything.

It works when loading index.html from the www folder.

What am I missing?

The sequence I used to create the project is:-

1. File > New Project
2. JavaScript -> Apache Cordova Apps -> Blank App (Apache Cordova)
3. Edit config.xml
4. Common -> Start Page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/
5. Common -> Domain Access: *
6. Platforms -> Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
7. Windows -> Windows target version: 10
8. Debug -> Windows Phone (Universal) -> Device (or Mobile Emulator 10)

After building and launching it does not load the specified start page, instead just showing a square and X splash screen.

Project Files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43876768/BlankCordovaApp1.zip

Comment: "Start Page(content)"  defines the app's starting page in the top-level web assets directory. See[Config.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#content). It doesn't support external page. If you want to reference external page see [Load external page on to Cordova/Phonegap application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798792/load-external-page-on-to-cordova-phonegap-application)